# Images in ArrayListAdapter get dissappear with scrolling up and down

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, lazy-loading

I am devloping an android application where i want to show Feeds (images, video thumnail, and text, and profile picutres) in ListView ArrayAdapter.
when listview adapter loads, then Username, profile picture (small size) and other text remains with scroll while the bigger imageview dissappear with scrolling. 
Below is my my adapter

```
 public class Adapter_All_Feeds extends ArrayAdapter<String>
 {
  private  Context context;

    String mUrl;
   ArrayList<String>feeds_id_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>feeds_email_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>feeds_name_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>feeds_path_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>feeds_profile_pic_path_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>feeds_description_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>feeds_date_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>feeds_time_lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    SingletonClass obj=SingletonClass.getInstance();

  int selected_pos=0;
  static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance

  public Adapter_All_Feeds(Context context, int pos,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_id_lst,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_email_lst,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_pic_path_lst,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_profile_pic_path_lst,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_description_lst,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_date_lst,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_time_lst,
          ArrayList<String> feeds_name_lst
          )
  {
    super(context, pos,feeds_email_lst);
    this.context = context;

    this.selected_pos=pos;
    this.feeds_email_lst=feeds_email_lst;
    this.feeds_id_lst=feeds_id_lst;
    this.feeds_path_lst=feeds_pic_path_lst;
    this.feeds_profile_pic_path_lst=feeds_profile_pic_path_lst;
    this.feeds_description_lst=feeds_description_lst;
    this.feeds_date_lst=feeds_date_lst;
    this.feeds_time_lst=feeds_time_lst;
    this.feeds_name_lst=feeds_name_lst;
  }

  static class ViewHolderItem 
  {
        TextView textViewItem;
        ImageView imgvw;
            ImageView picIV;   

           TextView nameTV;
           TextView datetimeTV;
           TextView descriptionTV;
          ImageView playIV;

    }
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {

   // LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView =convertView;
     //rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_all_feeds, parent, false);

     ViewHolderItem holder;
     if(rowView==null)
     {

         // inflate the layout
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_all_feeds, parent, false);
         holder = new ViewHolderItem();

         holder.imgvw=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         holder.picIV=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.SquareImageView01);   
         holder.nameTV=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         holder.datetimeTV=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
         holder.descriptionTV=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         holder.playIV=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);


         // store the holder with the view.
         rowView.setTag(holder);

     }
     else
     {

         holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
     }


     holder.nameTV.setText(""+feeds_name_lst.get(position));
  // datetimeTV.setText(""+feeds_date_lst.get(position)+" at "+feeds_time_lst.get(position));
     holder.descriptionTV.setText(""+feeds_description_lst.get(position));


   String date=""+feeds_date_lst.get(position);

    String[] parts = date.split("-");           
    int year1=2017,month1=1,day1=31;
    String month_name = "Jan";

    try
    {
     year1=Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
     month1=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
     day1=Integer.parseInt(""+date.substring(date.lastIndexOf('-') + 1).trim());
     month_name= ""+getMonthName(month1);

     holder.datetimeTV.setText(""+month_name+" "+day1+" at "+feeds_time_lst.get(position));

    }
    catch(NumberFormatException o)
    {
        //showtoast("Error:"+o.getMessage());
    }


    if(feeds_profile_pic_path_lst.get(position).length()>5)
    {


         String url="http://pir.alphasols.com/Moody_Android_App/User_Profile_Pictures/"+feeds_profile_pic_path_lst.get(position);
         setImagesUsingPicasso(url,holder.imgvw);  


    }
  //  else
    //  imgvw.setImageResource(R.drawable.add_photo_icon);


    if(feeds_path_lst.get(position).length()>5)
    {

        String type=feeds_path_lst.get(position).substring(feeds_path_lst.get(position).length() - 3);
        String url="http://pir.alphasols.com/Moody_Android_App/Phase_2_Php_Files/Feeds_n_WallFolder/"+feeds_path_lst.get(position);


     if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("png"))
     {
        holder.playIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.picIV.setImageResource(0);

        setImagesUsingPicasso(url,holder.picIV);

     }
     else
     {
            // url="http://pir.alphasols.com/Moody_Android_App/Phase_2_Php_Files/Feeds_n_WallFolder/pirzdata@gmail.com-2017-1-29-15:57:38.mp4";

  final     String mUrl=""+url;
  final ViewHolderItem holder2=holder;
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                String videoPath = ""+mUrl;
                MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
                try {
                    mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                        // no headers included
                        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
                    else
                        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
                    //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
                    bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) 
                        mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                if (bitmap != null)
                {
                 holder2.playIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                     
                 holder2.picIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            }
        }.execute();


     }

    }

    return rowView;
  }


    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
      //  return getItem(position).getContact().getId().hashCode();
        return feeds_id_lst.get(position).length();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }



  //(((( Retrive thaumnnail )))
  public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)
          throws Throwable
  {
      Bitmap bitmap = null;
      MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
      try
      {
          mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
              mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
              else
                  mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
       //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
          bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new Throwable(
                  "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                          + e.getMessage());

      }
      finally
      {
          if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null)
          {
              mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
          }
      }
      return bitmap;
  }


//((( Image Loading Using Picaso Library ))))
    private void setImagesUsingPicasso(final String URL,final ImageView imgVW) 
    {
         String url=URL;
          //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).fit().centerCrop().into(imgVW);

        Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(new Target()
        {

            public void onBitmapLoaded ( Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
            {
               // theView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);               
                //bitmap=getRoundedRectBitmap(bitmap, 100);
                imgVW.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0)
            {
            //Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.powered_by_google_dark);
            //icon=getRoundedRectBitmap(icon, 100);
          //  imgVW.setImageBitmap(icon);

            //  setImagesUsingPicasso(URL,imgVW);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) 
            {
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.powered_by_google_dark);
                //icon=getRoundedRectBitmap(icon, 100);
               // imgVW.setImageBitmap(icon);


            }
    });
     }      

    public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) 
    {

        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
               finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                            false);
        else
               finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                     finalBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                     finalBitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                     finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
                     finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;


    }


    private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) 
                        * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
                        + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
                        * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
                        * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

        dist =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(dist));
        return (dist);
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }

    //((( Pass Int value and return month in string  )))
            public String getMonthName(int month)
            {
                String month_name="Jan";

                switch(month)
                {

                case 1:
                    month_name="Jan";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    month_name="Feb";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    month_name="Mar";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    month_name="Apr";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    month_name="May";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    month_name="Jun";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    month_name="Jul";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    month_name="Aug";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    month_name="Sep";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    month_name="Oct";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    month_name="Nov";
                    break;
                case 12:
                        month_name="Dec";
                        break;
                }

                return month_name;
            }


    public void showtoast(String str)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


} //EOF Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {  //when image is at server,these two methods are needed to prevent unusual replacing of images.

    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}
```

Comment: Actually i am developing an app like facebook feeds, wher user profile with small size, name, and date and description are shown and below this is big image shows, so all others(user profile, name, date, etc) does not change with scoll, only the big image changes with scroll up and down

Comment: What is getCount and position

Comment: just add two methods in your adapter it will help you sure

Comment: now when i scroll down which loads more feeds, then i get thir error after implementing above code 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5